# Create new column

Tags: sql

I have a state table like this

[image: 1]

And a Data table like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JWC4.png)

What I'm trying to do is create a 'Target' column for my Data table

[image: 3]

So

```
case when (  first 2 letter from column [Cate_1] = [Abbreviation]
              or [Cate_1] start with State )
        and [Cate_2] like 'A20%' 
        then 'State'
   case when Cate_1 = "Customer_Name" 
        and [Cate_2] like 'A20%' 
        then 'State'
   else 'Correct'
   end
```

My first scenario is to get the 'State' value for [Target] column
My idea is using LEFT so

```
if left(Cate_1,2) = [Abbreviation]
                           or left (Cate_, ) = [State] 
                         then [State]
```

Please help if you know how to do this
Thank you so much.

Comment: You might accidentally shared same table twice.

Comment: @kaziMohammadAliNur you're right. thank you

Comment: (i) Should the ninth line actually read `then 'Customer'`? (ii) Where do you get the customer names from? (iii) Which database system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to derive the sample output from the sample input - using MySQL:

```
select
  d.Cate_1,
  d.Cate_2,
  'State' as Target
from State s
join Data d
  on left(d.Cate_2, 3) = 'A20'
  and
    ((left(d.Cate_1, 2) = s.abbreviation and length(d.Cate_1) = 4)
     or
     position(s.stateName in d.Cate_1) = 1
    )
union all
select distinct
  d.Cate_1,
  d.Cate_2,
  'Customer'
from State s
join Data d
  on left(d.Cate_2, 3) = 'A20'
  and
    (Cate_1 in ('Louis', 'Adam', 'Customer3')
    )
union all
select distinct
  d.Cate_1,
  d.Cate_2,
  'Correct'
from State s
join Data d
  on left(d.Cate_2, 3) <> 'A20'
order by 1
;
```

or

```
select
  d.Cate_1,
  d.Cate_2,
  case
    when d.Cate_1 in ('Louis', 'Adam', 'Customer3') and left(d.Cate_2, 3) = 'A20' then 'Customer'
    when left(d.Cate_2, 3) = 'A20' then 'State'
    else 'Correct'
  end as Target
from Data d
left join State s
  on left(d.Cate_2, 3) = 'A20'  
  and
    ((left(d.Cate_1, 2) = s.abbreviation and length(d.Cate_1) = 4)
     or
     position(s.stateName in d.Cate_1) = 1
    )
order by 1
;
```

**N.B.:**

- In general, you need to keep in mind, you might hit the same Data record more than once, e.g., "Alaska 01" with both "Alaska" and "AL" - at least if your server/session settings ignore upper/lower case. (That's why a `length` check has been added.)
- The customer names, could, of course, be read from a table as well.
- If you'd rather update the third column, that's feasible, too. - How exactly is largely depending on the database system used.
- The `order by` facilitates the comparison of the two result sets.

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b75a9d/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.